# May I vertically-align YAML values?

Tags: syntax, yaml, code-formatting

YAML code can get difficult to read and maintain, so like in other languages, I'd like to vertically-align "scalars".

For example, instead of this:

```yaml
breakfast:
  spam: 1
  hamHamHamHam: 2
  eggsEggs: 3
```

...I want this:

```yaml
breakfast:
  spam:         1
  hamHamHamHam: 2
  eggsEggs:     3
```

In the various YAML-based tools I'm using (which are mostly written in Python or Go), that seems to work. But I'm unsure whether that's valid YAML syntax, or whether those tools are not performing strict validation - and so my code could blow up some day.

I tested the above example with a well-known [linter](https://www.yamllint.com), which reported it valid - but as above, I don't know whether it is performing strict validation.

I scanned the current spec ([1.2.2](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/)) but couldn't find an answer.

Is the above format strictly valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't say I'm an expert in YAML, but according to the examples in the spec [1.2.2](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/), it is correct to align the values. Take the examples in [section 2.1 - Collections](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#21-collections).

According to these examples, it should be possible to use the semicolon next to the field name, or as a column separator.

Your example should be correct (example 2.4 of the spec):

```
breakfast:
  spam:         1
  hamHamHamHam: 2
  eggsEggs:     3
```

And also this format should be correct (example 2.12 of the spec):

```
breakfast:
  spam         : 1
  hamHamHamHam : 2
  eggsEggs     : 3
```

I'm pasting a screenshot because I couldn't format the examples correctly.

[image: Screenshot of the examples in the spec]

---

EDIT: Confirmed, it is described in [section 6.2 - Separation Spaces](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#62-separation-spaces):

> Outside indentation and scalar content, YAML uses white space characters for separation between tokens within a line. Note that such white space may safely include tab characters.
>
> Separation spaces are a presentation detail and must not be used to convey content information.

Comment: **Thanks, that must have been hard to find!** I scanned the doc and did a few choice searches but found nothing :-).